# Attach the most recent timestamp when value was changed to each row

Tags: sql, presto

I have a dataset of updated properties:

| user_id | flag | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 101 |
| 123 | 0 | 101 |
| 123 | 1 | 102 |
| 123 | 1 | 103 |
| 123 | 1 | 104 |
| 124 | 0 | 101 |
| 124 | 0 | 102 |
| 124 | 0 | 110 |

I need to assign to each row a value when was the most recent change of `flag` value, so it should look like this:

| user_id | flag | updated_at | recent_updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 101 | 101 |
| 123 | 0 | 102 | 102 |
| 123 | 1 | 103 | 103 |
| 123 | 1 | 104 | 103 |
| 123 | 1 | 105 | 103 |
| 124 | 0 | 101 | 101 |
| 124 | 0 | 102 | 101 |
| 124 | 0 | 110 | 101 |

I have this query so far, but feel stuck at the moment:

```
with raw_dataset as (
            SELECT 123 as user_id, 1 as flag, 101 as updated_at
  UNION ALL SELECT 123 as user_id, 0 as flag, 102 as updated_at
  UNION ALL SELECT 123 as user_id, 1 as flag, 103 as updated_at
  UNION ALL SELECT 123 as user_id, 0 as flag, 104 as updated_at
  UNION ALL SELECT 123 as user_id, 0 as flag, 105 as updated_at
  UNION ALL SELECT 124 as user_id, 1 as flag, 101 as updated_at
  UNION ALL SELECT 124 as user_id, 1 as flag, 103 as updated_at
  UNION ALL SELECT 124 as user_id, 1 as flag, 110 as updated_at

)
, dataset as (
select * from (
  select 
    *, 
--    lag(flag, 1, -1) over (partition by user_id order by updated_at ASC) as lag_,
    row_number() over (partition by user_id, flag order by updated_at ASC) as rn
  from raw_dataset
  )
)
SELECT *, first_value(updated_at) over (partition by user_id,flag order by rn ASC) FROM dataset 
ORDER BY user_id, updated_at ASC
```

Any ideas, tips?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to want the most recent time when the `flag` value changed.  Your question is rather confusing because the data in the question is different from the data in the code.

However, the follow returns the data in the question and what you want:

```
with raw_dataset as (
            SELECT 123 as user_id, 1 as flag, 101 as updated_at
  UNION ALL SELECT 123 as user_id, 0 as flag, 102 as updated_at
  UNION ALL SELECT 123 as user_id, 1 as flag, 103 as updated_at
  UNION ALL SELECT 123 as user_id, 1 as flag, 104 as updated_at
  UNION ALL SELECT 123 as user_id, 1 as flag, 105 as updated_at
  UNION ALL SELECT 124 as user_id, 0 as flag, 101 as updated_at
  UNION ALL SELECT 124 as user_id, 0 as flag, 103 as updated_at
  UNION ALL SELECT 124 as user_id, 0 as flag, 110 as updated_at
)
select rd.*,
       max(case when prev_flag is null or prev_flag <> flag then updated_at end) over (
            partition by user_id
            order by updated_at
           ) as most_recent_updated_at
from (select rd.*,
             lag(flag) over (partition by user_id order by updated_at) as prev_flag
      from raw_dataset rd
     ) rd;
```

The logic is pretty simple.  Just look at the previous flag.  Then do a cumulative `max()` when the value changes.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9d07da84db6aad630dded73a8450fc3b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: You're right! I need the most recent time when the flag was really updated, indeed. Let me edit the question.

Comment: @iurii_n . . . Then this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you need

```
with raw_dataset as (
            SELECT 123 as user_id, 1 as flag, 101 as updated_at
  UNION ALL SELECT 123 as user_id, 0 as flag, 102 as updated_at
  UNION ALL SELECT 123 as user_id, 1 as flag, 103 as updated_at
  UNION ALL SELECT 123 as user_id, 0 as flag, 104 as updated_at
  UNION ALL SELECT 123 as user_id, 0 as flag, 105 as updated_at
  UNION ALL SELECT 124 as user_id, 1 as flag, 101 as updated_at
  UNION ALL SELECT 124 as user_id, 1 as flag, 103 as updated_at
  UNION ALL SELECT 124 as user_id, 1 as flag, 110 as updated_at

)
, dataset as (
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by user_id order by updated_at ASC) 
    - row_number() over (partition by user_id, flag order by updated_at ASC) as grp
  from raw_dataset
)
SELECT *, min(updated_at) over (partition by user_id, flag, grp)
FROM dataset 
ORDER BY user_id, updated_at ASC
```

Comment: Not really, line number 3 should have 103 also, as previous line has 0 as flag and this one 1.https://prnt.sc/126wzop

Comment: Added `flag` to `min(updated_at) over (partition by user_id, flag, grp)`. Please check the corrected answer.

Comment: looks correct! Would you explain this part about taking a row number difference?

Comment: Due to the same ordering row number difference is constant till flag or userid is changed. So it is the group identity  within flag + userid